# How can I place a div over a canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas

Please note, I have tried other methods. How do I get the canvas to become a "background" for the div?
HTML:

```
<div style="z-index: 1; position: relative;">
  <div id="fireworks"><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></div>
</div>
<div class="page" style="z-index: 50000; height: 100%;">
  <form id="signup-form">
    <input style="display:none">
    <input type="password" style="display:none">
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give "div" and "canvas" same height and width. and canvas should be inside div.
like this-->

HTML/CSS

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 400px">
  <canvas style="width: 100%; height:100%"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't exactly see how this would fit in the code. Could you add it in for me?

Comment: You may also wanna do `<canvas style="... z-index:-1">` to place the canvas **below** other `div` elements.  Otherwise the canvas prevents you to click on those elements.

Answer (score 0):

set margin for 'canvas', and z-index for 'div' so div appear just above the canvas.

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 400px; z-index: 10; background-color:transparent"></div>
<canvas style="margin-top: -400px; width: 500px; height: 400px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Now I can't see the canvas element (fireworks) at all.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can always just set the canvas as the background image with

```
var whatEverSize = 100;
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = whatEverSize;
canvas.height = whatEverSize;
// set the canvas as the element background of the image type jpeg and medium
// compression 
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.background = "url(" + canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5) + ")";
```

That way you can tile, scale, clip using CSS.

Only problem is this is not practical if you are doing a lot of rendering to the canvas.